# A question about admin password

Tags: 12.04

I am updating UBUNTU 14.04 then machine is restart then after currect username and password not login successfully.What can I do???

Comment: I suggest reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery. There are some step by step instructions for password recovery.

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether the keyboard settings of the login are correct. You could also type the password once in the user name field to see whether the password looks like what you think it should look like. You could also test with or without caps.